# How do I write time-series data using asgraphite on an existing graphite server?

Tags: graphite, aerospike, asgraphite

[Using this documentation](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/monitor/graphite), I understand that I can log a one-time value like this -

```
python /opt/aerospike/bin/asgraphite -l 'latency:' --start -g <graphite_host> -p <graphite_port>
```

Where  and  will be the details of the already running graphite server that we have.

But, how do I specify the namespace where I want to log? The graphite server already has some namespaces where data is being logged.

Also, does the daemon initiated by such a command support logging at preset intervals? Or do I need to setup a cron for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An updated version and documentation of the asgraphite python script can be found here.

https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-graphite

You can use --interval to specify reporting preset interval to graphite server.

> --interval GRAPHITE_INTERVAL
>                           How often metrics are sent to graphite (seconds)

Also you can get all namespaces and sets using the following options (i don't believe you can specify only one namespace, all namespaces would get reported. :

> -n, --namespace       Get all namespace statistics
>   -s, --sets     Gather set based statistics

You also have the option of using a prefix. The default prefix is : instances.aerospike.

> --prefix GRAPHITE_PREFIX
>                           Prefix used when sending metrics to Graphite server
>                           (default: instances.aerospike.)

Comment: So how often will the reporting happen in case of older versions of asgraphite which come with say, Aerospike version 3.10?

Comment: Looks like in the old days it was hardcoded to an interval of 30 seconds

Comment: https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-graphite/blame/e19d6d86f16b657bcb97ff1289cba7f33054b33c/asgraphite.py#L352